# VMDebugger add-in crashes each time Visual Studio opens up

Tags: visual-studio-2012, vmware

I'm experiencing the following error each time I open up an instance of VS 2012, **for about a week**
(so it's not due to the yesterday's *Update 4*).

[image: Error]

Even if I click *Yes*, the error is shown again when I re-open Visual Studio.

Anyway, the VMWare debugger seems to be correctly loaded
(actually I don't use it, it came with VMWare workstation).

I can't isolate a single operation that caused the error to start appearing.

Anyone is experiencing the same error?

Comment: did you have resharper installed?  This appears to happen to me when you apply the keyboard scheme's for resharper.

Comment: @BlackICE No, i've not

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This worked for me:

completely uninstall VMWare workstation, reinstall it (select or deselect the VS plugin as you wish)

***old school***

Answer (score 59):

**[Edit]** See Attilas answer for a much easier solution producing the same result **[/Edit]**

For anyone who could not solve this problem by re-installing the VMWare plug-in but do not want to sacrifice all his VS settings, here is a solution that did work for me:

- Export 'Menu and Command Bar Customizations' VS settings **only** using

  `Tools => Import and Export Settings... => Export selected environment settings`

  - Deselect 'All Settings'
  - Select only 'All Settings/General Settings/Menu and Command Bar Customizations'
- Open exported `.vssettings` file in a text editor, scroll to the end and remove the entry `<add_toolbar Menu=... Name='VMware' .../>` in the `UserCustomizations` section
- Import edited `.vssettings` file using

  `Tools => Import and Export Settings... => Import selected environment settings`

and restart Visual Studio to check if the error has gone.

Comment: GREAT solution! not only it preserve our VS settings but also solves the problem without need to removing the VMware debugger plugin thing, great job!

Comment: It's a shame visual studio doesn't let you do this sensibly via the front end, and that Vmware can't fix their installer.

Comment: Great fix! I too could not modify VMware installation to repair/modify the plugin.

Comment: thats the solution. thanx

Answer (score 44):

I know this is an old thread, but I solved this problem with a rather simple step. Had the same scenario, clicking Yes in the popup window didn't change a thing.

What worked for me: you should start VS as an administrator, wait for the popup window and click Yes. After that the popup never came up again (even when VS was run as a non-administrator). So there was no need for me to uninstall the VMWare pluging (or the whole VMWare WS).

Comment: this worked for me, buygrush's answer did not work since VMWare wasn't anywhere in the settings file.

Comment: Worked for me with Microsoft Visual Studio Premium 2013, Version 12.0.40629.00 Update 5

Answer (score 10):

Run the VMware Workstation installer 
Choose Modify/Change
Uncheck Visual Studio Plugin
Problem gone!

Run the VMware Workstation installer 
Choose Modify/Change
Check Visual Studio Plugin
Problem back again!

Regards
Lemmy

Comment: Installer in Control Panel says "Use original VMware Workstation Installer". Original installer says "Setup has detected a newer version of VMware Workstation on your system". No luck.

Answer (score 7):

one possible solution:

```
Tools => Import and Export Settings => Reset all settings
```

seems to work for me.

Comment: I have hundreds of custom settings in VS, really cannot reset them all. See my answer, anyway thank u for your contribution, upvoted.

Answer (score 6):

VS 2013

```
Tools > Customize.. > Toolbars
```

Here I selected VMware and clicked Delete button.

I really don't use this plugin, this was the easiest solution for me.

Answer (score 5):

None of the solutions here worked for me since I have already uninstalled vmware a long time ago and I was not willing to re-install it again.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386106.aspx) suggests that there should be a registry key under

```
Root\Software\Microsoft\Visual Studio\...\AddIns\...
```

for VMdebugger, just delete that entry (the whole folder) and it'll be gone.

Comment: +1 for this. For VS2012 the key is HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\AddIns" deleted the VMDebugger.Connect key, problem solved.

Comment: Instead of deleting the node, you can also set `LoadBehavior` value under this key to 0 (default is 1). This fixed the problem for me leaves the possibility of reenabling it later if needed (as others have said, the add-in actually seems to work fine, it just gives an error on loading for some reason).

Answer (score 2):

If the option to install for all users was requested these Registry entries must also be removed.

HKEY_USERS.DEFAULT\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0_Config\Addins\VMDebugger.Connect
HKEY_USERS.DEFAULT\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0_Config\AddIns\VMDebugger.Connect

They correspond to the following HKCU entries. Hunt and kill.
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0_Config\Addins\VMDebugger.Connect
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0_Config\Addins\VMDebugger.Connect

Comment: Actually not a real answer, anyway thank u for your contribution. Upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

[image]From VS2012 menu bar select [Tools] [Add-in Manager]
Then check mark the radio box to install VMDebugger.

Worked on my system:
Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2012
Version 11.0.61030.00 Update 4
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.5.51209
Installed Version: Professional
Visual Studio Integrated Virtual Machine Debugger